UserControl DoubleBuffered = true is causing a memory leak
Project targets the .NET Framework 4.8
I have a UserControl with DoubleBuffered = true. When the calling form invalidates the UserControl, the PrivateMemorySize64 increases by 1000 bytes each time. The Paint handler is commented out so that's not the cause. The test program will crash after 14 hours with an OutOfMemoryException.
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class BitmapRender : UserControl
{
    private Bitmap TestBmp = new Bitmap(@"D:\test.bmp");

    public BitmapRender()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoubleBuffered = true; // This line is causing PrivateMemorySize64 to increase

        // this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.This_Paint);            

    }

    /*
    private void This_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(TestBmp, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);          
    }
    */
        
}

MAIN FORM
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // executes every 200 ms
        BitmapRender1.Invalidate();// this is causing a memory leak when DoubleBuffered = true in the UserControl;
    }
}


I was expecting the PrivateMemorySize64 to stay constant.

Not so sure you'll have a lot of SO users trying this out.  But there's a generic issue in Winforms, it is easy to create a functional UI that doesn't use enough managed memory.  Wrapper classes like Form, Bitmap, Pen, Brush, etc, use a lot of unmanaged resources but are very small managed classes that don't use a lot of GC heap.  You can easily run out of unmanaged memory before a GC collection kicks in.  Use the diagnostic tools in VS, pay attention to the yellow triangles while exercising the program.  If you don't get any then you'll have to help with GC.Collect()

I'm not using any gdi+ objects such as brushes, pens, fonts, etc. in my test program. At this point, I'm convinced there's a memory leak when DoubleBuffered = true or ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer is set, when any control is invalidated. I have implemented the BufferedGraphics class and the memory leak has disappeared.

@BobAune I tested using 4.5.2 and 4.7.2 and the memory stabilized at 6092 KB. I don't have 4.8 installed. Unless there is other code in the partial classes, I was unable to see a memory leak.
